# Error: fix the version conflict (google-services plugin) using productFlavors

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I know there are version conflicts, but issue still persists after new versions from Google.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processCurrentDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.0.

My **build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.x"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        legacy {
            minSdkVersion 9

        }
        current {
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }

}

    dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    legacyCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    legacyCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

    currentCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.0'
    currentCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My Build.gradle : (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**What changes are required now?**

Thank you,

Comment: Can you also show your root level build.gradle file please. It should have something similar to this in it:
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: Okay, I modified my question, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conflict is between a newer version of the plugin and the Play Services/Firebase dependencies.

You cannot apply different versions of the same plugin for different product flavors, thus you will run into this conflict when trying to use different Play Services dependencies in different flavors.

You can:

- Drop support for [the ~1% of users on API levels lower than 14](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) in new versions of your app
- Stay on an older Play Services/Firebase version that still supports 14

Answer (score 11):

The **real** solution is just to move the

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of the (app)build.gradle script and rebuild the project. Works 100%

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? This actually solved my build problems, but I don't get why...

Comment: That is a very good question which no one has an answer to. I think that it has to do something with referencing dependencies that have not yet been created.

Something like calling a variable before you even declare it.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Because apply plugin: `'com.android.application'` already has same package.

That's where the conflict arises.

Comment: @GowthamanM Where did you read this information? Check the official guidelines here. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: check if you add both  `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` conflict arises.

Comment: @Gowthaman M This is not the best answer, there is something wrong ! In any case thanks.